# Why does `go tool pprof` show addresses instead of function names?

Tags: go, pprof

```
$ go tool pprof pgears.go profilefile.prof
addr2line: crackhdr: unknown header type
Welcome to pprof!  For help, type 'help'.
(pprof) top
Total: 8 samples
       5  62.5%  62.5%        5  62.5% 0000000000028a8b
       1  12.5%  75.0%        1  12.5% 000000000002295c
       1  12.5%  87.5%        1  12.5% 000000000009375a
       1  12.5% 100.0%        1  12.5% 00000000000d278a
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1  12.5% 000000000000252a
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1  12.5% 000000000000259d
       0   0.0% 100.0%        2  25.0% 0000000000017d9e
       0   0.0% 100.0%        2  25.0% 000000000001a2bf
       0   0.0% 100.0%        6  75.0% 000000000001b630
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1  12.5% 0000000000045401
(pprof)
```

Why `go tool pprof` shows addresses instead of function names?
from http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/cpuprofile.html
or http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs
We know it must be function name.

Or how can I change the byte information to function name?

Operation System: Mac OS 10.9.2
Go Version: go1.2 darwin/amd64

Comment: I didn't face such problem before, but I think that `addr2line: crackhdr: unknown header type` line is the root of the problem.

Comment: See also: [discussion on `go-nuts`](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/X3ZZsEXHA_o/CWfjlEphwZEJ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first argument to `pprof` must be a *binary*, not a source file.

So you must compile the binary:

```
$ go build -o ppears
```

and use it as the input to `pprof`:

```
$ go tool pprof pgears
```

Comment: How do I get the binary?

Comment: @lincoln You compile the source file: `$ go build -o pgears.go` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
go build -o bin // build the binary file

go tool pprof bin profilefile.prof
```